# Gen 1&2 catchable Pokemon in Heartgold

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

I will start playing Heartgold, but no trading will occur with outside of the game itself.

My goal, except from becoming the very best ( :) ), is to catch all the available Gen 1 & 2 Pokemon in this game, and evolve them as much as I can.

Do you know which these Pokemon are? I cannot find a concrete list while surfing the Internet..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of generation 1 & 2 can be acquired in either HeartGold or SoulSilver. However, with just HeartGold some will be unavailable.

- The 2 Johto and 2 Kanto starters (and their evolutions) that you didn't choose will be unavailable. You need to trade to get the ones you didn't select.
- Vulpix, Ninetales, Meowth, Persian, Kabuto, Kabutops, Ledyba, Ledian, Skarmory, Tediursa, Ursaring and Delibird are unavailable, as they are SoulSilver exclusives.
- Mew and Celebi are only available from giveaways, so it is unlikely you will be able to catch them.
- Alakazam, Machamp, Golem, Gengar, Politoed, Slowking, Kingdra, Scizor, and Porygon 2 require trading to evolve. Steelix can still be encountered and caught without having to evolve Onix.
- You can get all of Tyrogue and Eevee's evolutions by breeding them with a Ditto, so all 3 hitmons and all 5 eeveelutions are possible in one game.

This leaves a total of 35 unacquirable Pokémon. You can consider your Pokédex complete at **216**.

Source for version exclusive lists: [HeartGold/SoulSilver Version Exclusive Pokémon on Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_HeartGold_and_SoulSilver_Versions#Game-exclusive_Pok.C3.A9mon)

Comment: Shouldn't the target number be 251 - 33 = 218 (and not 223)? I think you didn't count the eeveelutions? Also, I think that the uncatchable Pokemon are not 33, but 35, since you forgot to mention Teddiursa and it's evolution, Ursaring. So, the catchable Pokemon should be **216** then, don't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

The number of catchable Pokemon in Pokemon Heartgold is **216**.

Studoku's answer is almost correct (see comments).